# Pass onClick to material-ui button - works only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to wrap material-ui button into another component. Everything goes fine unless I've tried to handle onClick event. It seems that it works only once.

(not) Working example available at:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-nn0ut?fontsize=14

Source code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import MaterialButton from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { Component } from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const stylesMain = {
  root: {
    fontSize: 16
  }
};

const stylesSecondary = {
  root: {
    fontSize: 14
  }
};

const StyledButtonMain = withStyles(stylesMain)(MaterialButton);
const StyledButtonSecondary = withStyles(stylesSecondary)(MaterialButton);

class Button extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClick = function() {};
    this.href = null;
    this.target = null;
    this.type = "button";
    if (props.onClick) {
      this.onClick = props.onClick;
    }
    if (props.href) {
      this.href = props.href;
    }
    if (props.target) {
      this.target = props.target;
    }
    if (props.type) {
      this.type = props.type;
    }
  }

  render() {
    const StyledButton =
      this.props.color === "secondary"
        ? StyledButtonSecondary
        : StyledButtonMain;
    return (
      <StyledButton
        type={this.type}
        href={this.href}
        target={this.target}
        onClick={this.onClick}
        variant="contained"
        style={{ whiteSpace: "nowrap" }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </StyledButton>
    );
  }
}

export default function Counter(props) {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Counter: {counter}</h1>
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          setCounter(counter + 1);
        }}
      >
        ClickMe
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've expected, that onClick should work in the same manner as in "bare" material ui button. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you're binding the `onClick` function in the `Button` constructor. As you may know, the constructor function is only called once, whenever an instance of the `Button` class is created.

In your case, you're basically binding the `setCounter` function with a fixed value of 1 right in the constructor and from that point on, you ignore the function values passed in the `onClick` prop.

---

To fix this, all you need to do is replace the following line in the `Button` render function:

```
onClick={this.onClick}
```

With this one:

```
onClick={this.props.onClick}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are losing the value of onClick() between renders.  On initial load it will set it based on the prop, but then the next time it renders it loses the value since you aren't loading it again.

You can just use the props directly like below and use ternary operators like I did for onClick for null checks if you want

```
class Button extends Component {

  render() {
    const StyledButton =
      this.props.color === "secondary"
        ? StyledButtonSecondary
        : StyledButtonMain;
    return (
      <StyledButton
        type={this.props.type}
        href={this.props.href}
        target={this.props.target}
        onClick={this.props.onClick ? this.props.onClick : () => {}}
        variant="contained"
        style={{ whiteSpace: "nowrap" }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </StyledButton>
    );
  }
}
```